# How to filter attribute by its option value in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, filter, custom-attributes

I want to filter attribute by its option value in Magento2.2.5.
I have tried with this:
`$collection->addAttributeToFilter('collections', 258);`

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of attribute? Dropdown?.This code should be run.

Answer (score 0):

Do You load collection after this?
I mean sth like

```
$result = $collection->load();
```

or

```
$result = $collection->get...()
```